# Overriding HTML within certain class in CSS

Tags: css

I have following code:

```
div(class="class1")
    md-input-container
```

In CSS I want to override md-input-container css that only happens below `class1`.

The original way to override it:

```
md-input-container:not(.md-input-invalid).md-input-focused .md-input {
    border-color: red;
}
```

How to refer it to be only within `class1` only?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp Select and style every <p> element that are placed immediately after <div> elements:div + p { 
    background-color: yellow;
}

Comment: Tried it by this way `.class1 + md-input-container:not(.md-input-invalid).md-input-focused .md-input`, but not working..

Comment: directly inside should be: .class1 > md-input-container:not(.md-input-invalid).md-input-focused .md-input    hope this may work

Comment: unfortunately, not too..

Comment: @Rendy can you share your html structure ? ( just relevant stuff )

Comment: I think those are the only related things. I use Jade + Angular JS Material though..

Comment: well without a structure . to see what those classes are. how are the items structured inside the `.class1` we can't help you.

those classes ( .md-input-invalid,.md-input-focused ) are classes of the `md-input-container` ?

Comment: Well, actually the `md-input-container` is not direct child of `class1`, but 2-3 nested children inside. May be it's the problem?

Comment: if you want to edit that one. just use ` ` ( space ) like so `class1 md-input-container` this will select the `md-input-container` which is inside `.class1` regardless if it's  direct child or not. or you could use a path like if `md-input-container` is inside `.container` which is inside `.class1` use : `.class1>.container>md-input-container` . but again...it depends on the structure. it would be great if you could share so i can see where exactly `md-input-container` is situated or what are those classes `.md-input-invalid` and `.md-input-focused `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120107/discussion-between-mihai-t-and-rendy).

Comment: Thanks Mihai it works! I think it didn't work yesterday, but now it works!